# How do I access Quick Docs for Android Studio Flamingo 2022.2.1 patch

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-flamingo

In the past, I could press <kbd>Ctrl></kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and the Quick Docs would display using an older version of Android Studio. Now that I'm using the latest Android Studio Flamingo 2022.1 patch, it won't pop up.

How do I access quick docs now?